# How to adjust constraint in below IOS 13

Tags: ios, swift

I am using **xcode 11**.
My project is running in target **version 10.0**.
It is **working fine in iOS-13**.
My button constraint **is not working in iOS-12**.
I have used code below:

```
actionButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
actionButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
actionButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
actionButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

Please help me how to write constraints to make it working in iOS 12

Comment: Is it not working in iOS 12?

Comment: @Rob till not working. But it is working IOS-13

Comment: @Rob In IOS-13 Button is top & IOS-12 button is bottom

Comment: Have you added `actionButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`?

Comment: @Rob yes it is false

Comment: Are you getting any constraint breakouts error in the debugger?

Comment: @Rob No. I have used bellow like ..actionButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false     
              self.view.addSubview(actionButton)
        Constraint.activate([
            (actionButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor, constant: 30)),
            (actionButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20)),
            (actionButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)),
                (actionButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50))
                ])

Comment: @Rob I want the button start from top right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207153/discussion-between-rob-and-enamul-haque).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what you showed in the chat you are using DTZFloatingActionButton (which should have been mentioned in your question) and it uses it's own positioning if you don't provide some frame in initialization. So to fix this just create a button with any frame like this:

```
let actionButton = DTZFloatingActionButton(frame: .zero)
```

Though I'd also recommend using UIButton with customizations you need. This action button is just too smart and lacks usual button behaviour at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `view.layoutMarginsGuide` instead of `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide`. please check below code snippet.

```
let guide: UILayoutGuide!
   if #available(iOS 11.0, *){
        guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
   } else {
        guide = view.layoutMarginsGuide
   }

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        (actionButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor, constant: 30))),
        (actionButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide. trailingAnchor, constant: -20))),
        (actionButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)),
        (actionButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50))
        ])
```